# Upgrading to core 8.8 results in a path alias error

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have been trying to upgrade a site from Drupal 8.7.7 to 8.8, and following the release documentation, I upgraded the core and pathauto module at the same time.
So my composer.json has the core set to ^8.8, and pathauto to 1.8.

After running drush updb I get the following error in the console:

```
 [error]  ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '::conf' in module_load_include() (line 73 of /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/shortcut/shortcut.install) #0 /var/www/html/docroot/core/includes/module.inc(99): module_load_include('install', 'shortcut')
#1 /var/www/html/docroot/core/includes/install.inc(88): module_load_install('shortcut')
#2 /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/UpdateDBCommands.php(41): drupal_load_updates()
#3 [internal function]: Drush\Commands\core\UpdateDBCommands->updatedb(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(257): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
```

When I visit the front-end of the site I see the following:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Unable to replace alias "path.alias_whitelist" with actual definition "path_alias.whitelist". in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass->process() (line 57 of /var/www/html/docroot/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php).
```

Any idea how can successfully upgrade from Drupal 8.7.7 to 8.8?

Note: I still have a backup of the site and db, so an explanation on the upgrade would also work.

Answer (score 3):

Pathauto 8.x-1.6  is the only version working with both Drupal 8.7 and 8.8. So first update Pathauto to this version, then update core and then update Pathauto to the current version. Run `drush updb` in each step. See the change record http://drupal.org/node/3089457.