# Unable to install Pathauto, pathauto.settings already exists in active configuration

Tags: 8, upgrading

After upgrade from 8.7.10 to 8.9.13, i updated the pathauto module from ftp and trying to install from drupal admin but it showing an error like
"Unable to install Pathauto, pathauto.settings already exists in active configuration."

Based on the post
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-01-29/already-exists-in-active-configuration-issue
i deleted the pathauto.settings row from config table and cleared the cache and trying to install the module , but still showing the same error.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably did the core update having the wrong Pathauto version installed. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299833/upgrading-to-core-8-8-results-in-a-path-alias-error

Comment: Generally speaking, it's dangerous to jump multiple Drupal versions at once (from 8.7 to 8.9, you skipped 8.8).  8.8 has a breaking change to Pathauto as noted by 4k4, so you probably need to roll back to 8.7, update Pathauto, and then update core to 8.8, and then 8.9.

Comment: i updated first pathauto 1.6 and then to core 8.8.0 , but my entire site is broken . How to resolve this'

Answer (score 1):

**Before trying to do whatever I suggest below first of all have a full backup of the site.**

It seems pathauto module is not uninstalled properly.

To solve your problem you can just delete the `pathauto.settings` from config using drush.

Use the below command to delete the conflicting config.

`drush cdel pathauto.settings`

It will delete the existing pathauto configuration.Then you can install the pathauto module.

You should consider using composer for the module management.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following Drush command.

```bash
drush ev "\Drupal::service('config.manager')->uninstall('module', 'pathauto');"
```

After running it, you should be able to re-install the module.