# Upgrading core from 8.7.10 to 8.9.16

Tags: 8, updating

My current site version is running on Drupal 8.7.10 and I want to upgrade it to 8.9.16.

I backed up all the files and folders. Should I backup the Pathauto module, update the new Pathauto module, and start upgrading the site?
Are there other steps I need to take?
How can I proceed with the update?

Comment: See the comments below your question [Unable to install Pathauto, pathauto.settings already exists in active configuration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300447/unable-to-install-pathauto-pathauto-settings-already-exists-in-active-configura)

Comment: I am actually confused which things needs to be updated first, pathauto 8x-1.5 or core update and then pathauto

Comment: pathauto first.

Comment: I updated pathauto first and then drupal core from 8.7.10 to 8.8.0 , my site images and my sitemaps broke. How to resolve this