# Upgrading to 8.8.0 Receive PluginNotFoundException: The "group" entity type does not exist

Tags: 8, upgrading, group

I'm updating from 8.7.4 to 8.8.0. After updating core/modules and running "/update.php", I receive the follow error:

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "group" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 150 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager.php).

Any ideas? I am using the Group module, version 1.0-rc4, if that matters. (Not even clear to me if this error is related to the Group module or not...)

Here's my full composer.json if it helps...

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "composer/installers": "1.7",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/adaptivetheme": "^3.1",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.0",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.19",
        "drupal/business": "^1.7",
        "drupal/captcha": "1.2",
        "drupal/ckeditor_entity_link": "^1.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "8.8",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^2.1",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.3",
        "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^1.4",
        "drupal/editor_file": "^1.3",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.0",
        "drupal/group": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/gtranslate": "1.13",
        "drupal/imce": "^1.7",
        "drupal/owlcarousel2": "^1.0",
        "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/pager": "^2.0",
        "drupal/panels": "4.4",
        "drupal/pathauto": "1.6",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^2.3",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.14",
        "drupal/search_api_attachments": "^1.0",
        "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.2",
        "drupal/text_resize": "^1.2",
        "drupal/token": "^1.5",
        "drupal/url_to_video_filter": "^2.0",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "4.0.1",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.0",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "kint-php/kint": "^4.1",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "8.8"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": true,
            "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "enable-patching": "true",
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "patches": {
                    
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the full error page as well when running update.php (or trying to access the site in any manner):

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem::schema() (Line: 451)
Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig->getSchema() (Line: 488)
Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig->getColumns() (Line: 320)
views_field_default_views_data() (Line: 772)
core_field_views_data()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 392)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke() (Line: 191)
views_views_data()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 392)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke() (Line: 245)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 162)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get() (Line: 91)
Drupal\ds\Plugin\Derivative\DsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions() (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives() (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 146)
views_theme() (Line: 447)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension() (Line: 334)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build() (Line: 233)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get() (Line: 88)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (Line: 69)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct() (Line: 253)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 142)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 144)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 145)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot() (Line: 66)
Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage() (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage() (Line: 196)
Drupal\system\Controller\DbUpdateController->handle()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 115)
Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handle() (Line: 28)
```

Comment: First, roll back your database and code to a version prior to running `update.php` (to make sure that the DB is not in a weird, half-zombie state). Then I recommend updating core and modules in two separate deployments (i.e. update core first and deploy, then update modules and deploy). This will help you figure out which update is causing issues.

Comment: I think we have to update pathauto to 1.6 at least... Then go from there. This is a good troubleshooting step, but I'm surprised nobody else has run into this issue so far.

Comment: When you're this far back, it's better to upgrade each module one at a time, running the DB update script in-between, and after all modules have been updated, then update core.

Comment: @rjbullock I believe everyone has encountered this in one form or another. It's just that it manifests in a different way depending on the combination of modules you have installed and the state of your database. I did an 8.6 to 8.8 update once, and pathauto did come up as one of a handful of modules that prevented a straight-up update. I had to piece by piece rule out modules down to the version, and come up with a process to deploy changes piece by piece as well.

Comment: @rjbullock, Pathauto was a very special case because the core alias table was converted to an entity in Drupal 8.8.0. This is in the release notes of this version and there was even a core change record (for a contrib module!). See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299833/upgrading-to-core-8-8-results-in-a-path-alias-error